# FOSUserBundle: User doesn't get roles of group

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using symfony 2.5 and trying to check if a user has a specific role. The tables are set up correctly in the database and the data is correct inserted:

In the database exists a user `test@example.com` with a mapped group `admin` which has defined the roles `a:1:{i:0;s:10:"ROLE_ADMIN";}`

I don't know why the roles aren't read correct. The debug-toolbar tells me, that i am only authenticated as `ROLE_USER`.

Code:

```
$securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context');    
$securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN');

if ($securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
    echo 'crazy coding magic happens here';
}
```

I have found this question ([Symfony 2 FOS UserBundle users doesn't get group's role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056583/symfony-2-fos-userbundle-users-doesnt-get-groups-role)) which seems to be related to my question, but i am not satisfied with the answer, because i don't want to check the group-access but the role-access. In my case group permissions could change in the future.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay - it seems i have found the solution by myself.

The problem is that you have to sign off the logged in user and sign in again to recognize changes in the group-role-mapping.

The code above is correct and after the is user is logged in again the correct roles are assigned.