# isGranted returns FALSE with User extending FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

For the simplicity of the problem I am not using role_hierarchy on my security.yml.

I have a logged user. If I do this on my controller:

```
dump($this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser()->getRoles());
```

This is what I get:

```
array:3 [▼
0 => "ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN" 
1 => "ROLE_ADMIN" 
2 => "ROLE_USER"
]
```

But then if I ask for isGranted, I just get true on 'ROLE_USER', and false with all the rest:

```
dump($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_USER'));
dump($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN'));
dump($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN'));
```

gives me:

```
true
false
false
```

I am using FOSUserBundle and my user extends their BaseUser (which on turn implements UserInterface) and I am not touching any method of it on my User entity.

Can you spot the problem? Is that I can not use the security.checker with FOSUSerBundle?

UPDATE:
If I dump($this->getUser()) this is what I get:

```
Usuario {#2290 ▼
#id: 3
#username: "u1"
#usernameCanonical: "u1"
#email: "u1"
#emailCanonical: "u1"
#enabled: true
#salt: "8wqvgv5t24g0ssck44gw4008c04g8sg"
#password:        "zfDmozi78wrglXx3SUaCiz7490o4ZzKYEukcbdlCQ5FAWpA4jgLFQT6BXNbo3tzTyhdPDOCC/h4ZDs32SKlGEw=="
#plainPassword: null
#lastLogin: DateTime {#2288 ▶}
#confirmationToken: null
#passwordRequestedAt: null
#groups: null
#locked: false
#expired: false
#expiresAt: null
#roles: array:2 [▼
0 => "ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN"
1 => "ROLE_ADMIN"
]
#credentialsExpired: false
#credentialsExpireAt: null
}
```

As you can see, FSOS just add the 'ROLE_USER' in getRoles() method since it is not present in the actual array of Roles.

Comment: So the user has three separate roles assigned to it in the DB? I just tested it using your code and it returns correctly for me (but I have hierarchies). Could you dump `$this->getUser()` and put that up here?

Comment: updated! I really dont know where the problem could be. thank for helping me out @bassplayer7.

Comment: That is strange. I will continue to think about it. Do you use XDebug? Have you stepped through it with that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654270/fosuserbundle-user-doesnt-get-roles-of-group

Did you log out and log in again?

Answer (score 3):

Logging out and back in again will resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me and I was getting mad :)

Comment: No problem. The session stores role information, so it has to be cleared.